# How to create pointer variable from a reference type in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a global pointer so that all the functions can access the reference.

I've tried assigning the address of reference to a pointer but when I try to access the values getting compilation error.

```cpp
vector<vector<char>>* table;

class Solution {
public:
    void solveSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
        table = &board;
        cout << board[0][0] << "\n" << table[0][0];
    }
};
```

```
Line 70: Char 37: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>::value_type' (aka 'std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>'))
        cout << board[0][0] << "\n" << table[0][0];
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/cstddef:130:5: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>' to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
    operator<<(byte __b, _IntegerType __shift) noexcept
    ^
```

Comment: It's not the assignment that makes it fail.

Comment: You should dereference the pointer as `(*table)[0][0]`.

Comment: @songyuanyao, I can access the values that way but why dereferencing is needed if we are using square brackets?

Comment: @Sarthak This is the same as any other pointer. The first `[0]` tells the compiler "`table` points to an array of `vector<vector<char>>` and I want the first one". Think of how `int x[10]; int * ptr = x; ptr[4] = 5;` works.

Comment: @Sarthak Because `operator[]` is supposed to be applied on the `vector`, not the pointer to `vector`.

Comment: oh, I get it now, Thanks!

Comment: @Sarthak You could also write `(*table)[0][0]` as `table[0][0][0]` if you prefer, but without either of those your code is off by 1 level of indirection.

Comment: Why is there a need to create a pointer from a reference?

Comment: Usually you use references *instead of* pointers, using pointers in C++ is where things get very messy. What's the goal here that requires pointers?

Comment: I don't see why you make it a global variable at all. If you have a class in the first place, why not make it a member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `(*table)[0][0]`.

`table[0]` is equivalent to `(*table)` (the vector of vector `board`).

so `table[0][x]` is just `board[x]`.

and `vector` is not streamable.

Answer (score 0):

You code fails to compile for reason described by others, that you actually do not dereference  a pointer `(*table)[0][0]`, in result expression returns wrong type

A C++ [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) is an alias of original object "bound" to it, it's literally not possible to get address or value of reference itself, you would obtain address and value of bound object. In some cases reference doesn't have memory representation at all, on others it's actually an address, but standard doesn't define that.
In case of function's argument passed by reference, the object represented by argument expression is bound to to the name of function's parameter, in your case it's the `board`, until end of function call. After that, if object was temporary and we could somehow store the reference, reference would be dangling:

```
void foo (Type& a)
{
    static Type& ref  = a; // BAD idea. this initialization happens only once
    // but on second call `ref` may refer to non-existing instance of Type
}
```

If you for some odd reason need a container that behaves like reference, there is [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), but it's a class which rarely used directly, rather it is used when implementing containers.

PS. You have another problem, by default `char` is treated as a letter by streams. You probably would want to store elements of sudoku as  a enum or another integral type , or keep in mind that you have to cast.

PPS. I wouldn't use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` type here. I would rather go with OOP style and create class that encapsulates board functions, e.g. (it's a sketch laking of some details, e.g. fault protection)

```
class Sudoku {
public:
    enum Number { none = 0, one = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine};
    
    Sudoku(int N) : rank(N), data(N*N, Sudoku::none) { }
    // add more constructors here if needed?
    
    // would allow to address particular element, e.g. board(i,j) 
    Number operator() (unsigned col, unsigned row) const
    { return data[row*rank + col];  }
    
    Number& operator() (unsigned col, unsigned row)
    { return data[row*rank + col];  }
    
    unsigned size() const {return rank;}
    
    // more operations, resize, a copy operation on board if required?
private:
    unsigned             rank; // size of board
    std::vector<Number>  data; // content of board
};
```